# PDO/PHP - bindValue does not seem to be working

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

According to everything I've found and seen, this seems correct. When I print $query the outcome is the following:

**"INSERT INTO customers (FirstName, MiddleInit, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email, Gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"**

The parameters should have been filled in with the variables in bindValues(). So, for example ...

**INSERT INTO customers (FirstName, MiddleInit, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email, Gender) VALUES (Bill, A, Hopkins, 123 Ave, ....)**

I'd like to stick with this method - it is surrounded by a try/catch block. From printing the query variable out I can see that is where the issue is.

What am I missing? I really appreciate you looking!

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO customers (FirstName, MiddleInit, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email, Gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
        echo $query;
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(1, $firstName);
        $statement->bindValue(2, $middle);
        $statement->bindValue(3, $lastName);
        $statement->bindValue(4, $address);
        $statement->bindValue(5, $city);
        $statement->bindValue(6, $state);
        $statement->bindValue(7, $zip);
        $statement->bindValue(8, $email);
        $statement->bindValue(9, $gender);
        $success = ($statement->execute());
```

Comment: no idea, not enough code to provide a solution. whether you are using PDO as the API to connect with and if your variables are indeed correct. Check for errors.

Comment: That isn't how prepared statements work. The statement stays as a query with placeholders (like a function with arguments) and when executed on the database, the bound parameters are injected (like calling the function)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a misunderstanding of prepared statements

Comment: @Phil Example #2 http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php states it, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement. @Fred-ii- I think OP is expecting the `$query` string to be changed by binding the values

Comment: I'll take a look at the links provided, thus far I haven't been able to find much on my own.

There are no errors.

Using PDO - yes, I was expecting the binding values to "auto populate" into the query, therefore changing it.

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

We need more code considering the error but you can try this with prepared statements:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO customers (FirstName, MiddleInit, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email, Gender) VALUES (:firstName, :middle, :lastName, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :gender)';
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':firstName'=>$firstName, ':middle'=>$middle, ':lastName'=>$lastName, ':address'=>$address, ':city'=>$city, ':state'=>$state, ':zip'=>$zip, ':email'=>$email, ':gender'=>$gender));
```

Comment: Whether OP is using positional or named parameters is not relevant